# DynamoDB Query For Value in String Set Or Map

Tags: arrays, list, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, fetch

I have a table on DynamoDB and I am trying to return items with a certain tag. So lets say the following is my schema. How do I query for all objects with a tag "Queen" within the string list? My app is in objective c.

UserId: User

Location: London

Tags: ["Queen", "Royalty", "England"]

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the solution to my problem. It was unclear to me how to write a filter expression without a basic operator. This solved my problem.

scanExpression.filterExpression = @"contains(Tags, :val)";

Comment: However I am unable to filter a map property